# Android minifyEnabled crash because of protobuf class

Tags: android, gradle, android-jetpack-compose, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to build an app using jetpack compose, therefore to improve the app prefromence I wanted to run and test the app on a release variant, and setting minifyEnabled to true in the gradle file.

but after doing so, when I tried to run the app I get this crash error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Field displayTheme_ for j6.g0 not found. Known fields are [public int j6.g0.e, public boolean j6.g0.f, public boolean j6.g0.g, public boolean j6.g0.h, public boolean j6.g0.i, public boolean j6.g0.j, public static final j6.g0 j6.g0.k, public static volatile oc.y j6.g0.l]
at oc.x0.I(SourceFile:63)
at oc.x0.z(SourceFile:675)
at oc.x0.y(SourceFile:13)
at oc.c1.a(SourceFile:150)
at oc.x.c(SourceFile:26)
at oc.x.b(SourceFile:1)
at g6.a.<init>(SourceFile:68)
...
```

I've searched in my files for this field: `displayTheme_` and it was only found in an auto generated class, that was created because of a protobuf class I've created:

```
/**
 * Protobuf type {@code settings.UserPreferences}
 */

public  final class UserPreferences extends
    com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite<
        UserPreferences, UserPreferences.Builder> implements
    // @@protoc_insertion_point(message_implements:settings.UserPreferences)
    UserPreferencesOrBuilder {
  private UserPreferences() {
  }
  public static final int DISPLAY_THEME_FIELD_NUMBER = 1;
  private int displayTheme_;
  ...
```

This is my gradle file (minus the dependencies):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.9.0'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version '1.8.10'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.test.testproj'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.testproj"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("debug")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.3'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.21.12"
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.14.0"
    }

    // Generates the java Protobuf-lite code for the Protobufs in this project. See
    // https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin#customizing-protobuf-compilation
    // for more information.
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is my protobuf class:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package settings;

option java_package = "com.test.testproj.model";
option java_multiple_files = true;

enum ThemeOptionProto {
  THEME_OPTION_AUTO = 0;
  THEME_OPTION_LIGHT = 1;
  THEME_OPTION_DARK = 2;
}

message UserPreferences {
  ThemeOptionProto display_theme = 1;
  bool vibrate_a = 2;
  bool vibrate_b = 3;
  bool vibrate_c = 4;
  bool vibrate_d = 5;
  bool display_lines = 6;
}
```

I've been trying to understand how to solve it, maybe adding proguard rules but how can I do it to auto generated classes?
am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like the used protobuf library uses reflection to find a field by it's name. If this happens you have to adapt your proguard configuration and "keep" (do not modify) the generated protobuf class. When obfucating apps using proguard this is common that you have to adapt your proguard configuration until the app works.

Comment: @Robert thanks ill try to keep the class and its members